# Generating a list of dates given the start and end dates

Tags: vba, date, excel

Previously I found some VBA code done by Andy Brown that generates a list and makes each date the first or 15th for another user. I have tried to adjust this code to my needs but I'm struggling. Currently the code, once run, is just putting in the same date over and over and I have to end Excel.

```
Sub GenerateDates()

Dim FirstDate As Date
Dim LastDate As Date
Dim NextDate As Date

FirstDate = Range("A1").Value
LastDate = Range("a2").Value

NextDate = FirstDate
Range("B1").Select

Do Until NextDate >= LastDate

    ActiveCell.Value = NextDate
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    If Day(NextDate) = 1 Then
        NextDate = DateAdd("d", NextDate, 14)
    Else
        NextDate = DateAdd("d", NextDate, 20)
        NextDate = DateSerial(Year(NextDate), Month(NextDate), 1)
    End If

Loop
```

Previous code I based my model upon is listed above and my, most likely terrible code, is below:

```
Sub GenerateDates()

Dim FirstDate As Date
Dim LastDate As Date
Dim NextDate As Date

FirstDate = Range("startdate").Value
LastDate = Range("enddate").Value

NextDate = FirstDate
Range("tripdays").Select
'selection of columns within one row
Do Until NextDate >= LastDate

    ActiveCell.Value = NextDate
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    If Day(NextDate) = 1 Then
        NextDate = DateAdd("d", NextDate, 14)

    End If

Loop

End Sub
```

What I need instead is to generate ***every*** date between the given start and end dates, instead of just the 15th and 1st. How is this done?

Comment: What exactly do you need? We don't know what you want to do with his code. If you're mainly adjusting it to your named ranges, then you don't have to remove the `Else` block from his code. Add that in and adjust to your ranges. :)

Comment: Instead of each date being separated by the 1st and the 15th I want the output to be every date between the range, so:

Start date = 1/1/2014
End Date = 1/6/2014

Output= 1/1/2014  1/2/2014  1/3/2014   1/4/2014  1/5/2014  1/6/2014


.....Also, how do I properly do the graying for the code like you did there? I literally started using VBA about a week ago so I'm hoping to learn and be able to contribute to others down the road.

Comment: Now that's better. Modifying my answer below. Wait a few.

Comment: See modified answer below. To turn your text into a codeblock in the editor, just paste it in, highlight it, and select the codeblock option. Alternatively, adding four (4) spaces before a line turns that line into a codeblock. Anyway, the solution to your problem is simple: you just need to `+1` the start date until it hits the end date. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:**

This is apparently what you need, as discussed in comments.

```
Sub GenerateDates()

Dim FirstDate As Date
Dim LastDate As Date
Dim NextDate As Date

FirstDate = Range("startdate").Value
LastDate = Range("enddate").Value

NextDate = FirstDate
Range("tripdays").Select
'selection of columns within one row
Do Until NextDate > LastDate

    ActiveCell.Value = NextDate
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    NextDate = NextDate + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

Alternatively, a `For` loop would do just as well.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**FURTHER EDIT:**

Horizontal version, as requested.

```
Sub GenerateDatesH()

Dim FirstDate As Date
Dim LastDate As Date
Dim NextDate As Date
Dim DateOffset As Range
Dim DateIter As Date

FirstDate = Range("startdate").Value
LastDate = Range("enddate").Value
Set DateOffset = Range("tripdays")

For DateIter = FirstDate To LastDate
    DateOffset.Value = DateIter
    Set DateOffset = DateOffset.Offset(0, 1)
Next DateIter

End Sub
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**Note:** I've also fixed the vertical version to stop at the end date provided.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have two more questions that I have a feeling will be VERY easy for you. Is there a way to make the output go horizontally instead of down a column? Also, is there a way to make the last date be the end date?

Comment: Doable. Wait a moment, I'll be adding a variation. :)

Comment: Far too slow. Never use .Select.

Comment: @EducateMe This is very old code. But I agree. I don't work with Excel now though but if VB is still the same, then `.Select` is still bad.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using select in code it is very inefficient :)

```
Sub p()
Dim FirstDate As Date
Dim LastDate As Date
Dim NextDate As Date
Dim r As Long
FirstDate = Range("A1").Value
LastDate = Range("a2").Value
r = 1
Do
 FirstDate = FirstDate + 1
 Cells(r, 2) = FirstDate
 r = r + 1
Loop Until FirstDate = LastDate
End Sub
```

to do it in a row replace cells(r,2) by cells(1, r) and start r=2