# Excel VB to create monthly table based on user input

Tags: excel, vb.net

I would like to create a monthly table where months are written in specific format "MMM-YY"

This will be based on specific input answers. I will ask a question where a response is entered in B1 for starting month (Jan-17). Same for ending month (Oct-18) where response is entered in B2. So the inputs in B1 and B2 creates a range of month...for example Jan-17 to Oct-18. Jan-17 and Oct-18 are just examples and it can be anything the user inputs.

In Column C thru X, a monthly table will be created starting from Jan-17 to Oct-18. 22 columns.

I can do this manually, but i am wondering if this can be done with VB.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course you can do that in VB. Best approach here would be to use VBA/Macro.

A way to learn how to to that by your own is to record a Macro one time. That is you do it one time manually and the macro records all the button clicks. Then you can take a look at the generated code for the recorded macro, so you can "learn how to do things programatically in Excel".

But see **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21761451/generating-a-list-of-dates-given-the-start-and-end-dates)** (if you need to do it in a VB.NET application you can use the Excel.Interop assembly and do just the same within your VB code), that should help you with your problematic. You can then format your date to write it as desired in Excel.

And you should "google" before posting, since I found a lot of answer for this problem, and in consecuence you would get negative votes for your question