# Creating a List on Another Sheet - Run-Time Error 9

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using the following code that I edited from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21761451/generating-a-list-of-dates-given-the-start-and-end-dates) to list all the dates between a start and end date.  The list is being created on a different sheet than the cells containing start and end dates.  The code works if I have sheet6 open, but not if I'm on sheet1.  I get a 'run-time error 9: subscript out of range.' Debugging highlights the reference to sheet6.  How can I amend this code to work regardless of the active sheet?

```
Sub GenerateDates()

Dim FirstDate As Date
Dim LastDate As Date
Dim NextDate As Date

FirstDate = Sheet1.Range("CZ").Value
LastDate = Sheet1.Range("DA").Value

NextDate = FirstDate
Worksheets("sheet6").Range("A1").Select
Do Until NextDate > LastDate

    ActiveCell.Value = NextDate
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    NextDate = NextDate + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Shouldn't" Worksheets("sheet6").Range("A1").Select" give you SOME sort of hint what to do?

Comment: You shouldn't use Select as it's inefficient and usually unnecessary. If you are going to, the problem here is that you must first activate the sheet and then select the cell - you can't select a cell on a sheet which is not active.

Comment: Oh ok, that's helpful.  I'll look into that.  Thank you for your reply. @SJR

Comment: My pleasure. As an aside, I assume CZ and DA are named ranges? Possible confusion with column letters so you might want to consider renaming.

Comment: That's good advice.  I'm really deep into my cell references for this sheet (800+), but I'll keep that in mind for future projects. @SJR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, always try to set and fully qualify your worksheet and range variables.  Then work with those directly instead of using Select/Activate.

```
Sub GenerateDates()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim rDest As Range
    Dim FirstDate As Date
    Dim LastDate As Date
    Dim NextDate As Date

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsData = wb.Sheets(1)
    Set wsDest = wb.Sheets(6)
    Set rDest = wsDest.Range("A1")

    FirstDate = wsData.Range("CZ").Value
    LastDate = wsData.Range("DA").Value
    NextDate = FirstDate

    Do Until NextDate > LastDate
        rDest.Value = NextDate
        Set rDest = rDest.Offset(1)
        NextDate = NextDate + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you.  I'm going to go through your code and really understand it so I can duplicate it in the future.  I really appreciate your help.